# Shreading Data From Oracle XMLType

Tags: oracle, xpath

I’ve been pulling my hair out over this (what is left) and was wondering if you see something I don’t in Oracle’s XPath logic. I researched the various functions and XPath methods through Oracle's documentation to no avail.

In the example's below, the table pg_xml_stg contains the attribute pressganey_xml (XMLType).  Sample of the contents below:

```
<PATIENTLEVELDATA>
                <SURVEY_ID>826434950</SURVEY_ID>
                <CLIENT_ID>7145</CLIENT_ID>
                <SERVICE>IN</SERVICE>
                <RECDATE>2014-11-26</RECDATE>
                <DISDATE>2014-07-04</DISDATE>
                <ANALYSIS>
                     <RESPONSE>
                             <VARNAME>A1</VARNAME>
                             <VALUE>5</VALUE>
```

Here is a query that pulls data down to the response level, but doesn’t include the data from the Patient Level (survey_id).   Not sure if my XPATH string is off or the actual xmlsequence call does not actually pull the data above ANALYSIS.

```
SELECT    extractvalue (Value (pg), '//VARNAME/text()') as PG_VARNAME
         ,extractvalue (Value (pg), '//VALUE/text()') as PG_VARNAME
         ,extractvalue (Value (pg), '../../SURVEY_ID/text()') as PG_VARNAME
FROM v500.pg_xml_stg
    ,TABLE (xmlsequence (extract (pressganey_xml, '//PATIENTLEVELDATA/ANALYSIS/RESPONSE'))) pg

PG_VARNAME  PG_VARNAME  PG_VARNAME
A1                           5              
A2                           5              
D1                           5              
D2                           5              
D3                           5              
I1                           5              
I17                          5              
I6                           5
```

I can get both in the query below by indexing the VARRAY, but it won’t allow for anything beyond level 1.

```
SELECT extractvalue (Value (pg), '//PATIENTLEVELDATA/SURVEY_ID/text()') as PG_SURVEY_ID
,extractvalue (Value (pg), '//PATIENTLEVELDATA/ANALYSIS[1]/RESPONSE[1]/VARNAME[1]/text()') as PG_VARNAME
,extractvalue (Value (pg), '//PATIENTLEVELDATA/ANALYSIS[1]/RESPONSE[1]/VALUE[1]/text()') as PG_VALUE
FROM v500.pg_xml_stg
, TABLE (xmlsequence (extract (pressganey_xml, '*/PATIENTLEVELDATA'))) pg

PG_SURVEY_ID                 PG_VARNAME  PG_VALUE
826434950                           A1                           5
830145105                           A1                           5
842152499                           A1                           4
846003814                           A1                           5
850619251                           D1                           3
850711623                           A1                           4
851482310                           A1                           5
```

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Can you expand the sample XML a bit? You only show one analysis with one response, so the structure isn't obvious (to me, anyway).

Comment: Alex, Thank you so much for solving this issue.  I was unable to find any Oracle documents that explained this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query the survey ID is not available because `pg` only contains the responses; the data above that in the original XML isn't available to the `extractvalue()` calls since it wasn't passed. What you're doing is analogous to passing the substr of a value to a function and expecting the function to know the entire original string.

In the second query you're only specifying the first instance of each node name, as you already know. And because there are multiple nodes at each level, potentially, you can't use `extractvalue()` anyway, and trying to get multiple nodes would throw `ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node`. And [`extractvalue()` is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173) anyway.

To get multiple values out you can use [the `XMLTable()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173) to transform your XML hierarchy into something more like relational data.

Your XML snippet doesn't show the whole structure or how nodes repeat, but working backwards from your queries and their results, something like this might be close enough to get the general idea:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
  <PATIENTLEVELDATA>
  <SURVEY_ID>826434950</SURVEY_ID>
  <CLIENT_ID>7145</CLIENT_ID>
  <SERVICE>IN</SERVICE>
  <RECDATE>2014-11-26</RECDATE>
  <DISDATE>2014-07-04</DISDATE>
    <ANALYSIS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>5</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A2</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>6</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>D1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>7</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>8</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A2</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>9</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>D1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>10</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
    </ANALYSIS>
  </PATIENTLEVELDATA>
  <PATIENTLEVELDATA>
  <SURVEY_ID>830145105</SURVEY_ID>
  <CLIENT_ID>7146</CLIENT_ID>
  <SERVICE>IN</SERVICE>
  <RECDATE>2014-11-27</RECDATE>
  <DISDATE>2014-07-04</DISDATE>
    <ANALYSIS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>3</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A2</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>4</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>D1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>7</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <VARNAME>A1</VARNAME>
        <VALUE>11</VALUE>
      </RESPONSE>
    </ANALYSIS>
  </PATIENTLEVELDATA>
</DATA>
```

Then a query like this:

```
select x.*
from pg_xml_stg pxs
cross join xmltable('for $i in //PATIENTLEVELDATA, $j in $i/ANALYSIS/RESPONSE
  return <tmp
      pg_survey_id="{$i/SURVEY_ID}"
      pg_varname="{$j/VARNAME}"
      pg_value="{$j/VALUE}"
    />'
  passing pxs.pressganey_xml
  columns
      pg_survey_id number path '/tmp/@pg_survey_id',
      pg_varname varchar2(10) path '/tmp/@pg_varname',
      pg_value number path '/tmp/@pg_value'
) x;
```

Gets output:

```
PG_SURVEY_ID PG_VARNAME   PG_VALUE
------------ ---------- ----------
   826434950 A1                  5 
   826434950 A2                  6 
   826434950 D1                  7 
   826434950 A1                  8 
   826434950 A2                  9 
   826434950 D1                 10 
   830145105 A1                  3 
   830145105 A2                  4 
   830145105 D1                  7 
   830145105 A1                 11 

 10 rows selected
```

That has all the response `VARNAME`/`VALUE` pairs with their parent nodes' `SURVEY_ID`.

The XPath flattens the data by using `$i` to get the `PATIENTLEVEL` nodes, and then within those `$j` to get the `RESPONSE` nodes related to each one. The values you're interested in are combined as attributes of a dummy `tmp` node in the `return` clause; which generates something like this for each response:

```xml
<tmp pg_survey_id="826434950" pg_varname="A1" pg_value="5" />
```

The `passing` clause just identified the XMLType column from your table and passes that into the XPath. And the `columns` clause converts the attributes from the dummy `tmp` node into relational columns.

I've guessed the survey ID and response values are numbers, but you can tweak all those data types to match what you really have.